# how to only sum a part of elements in a list

Tags: python, sum

I need this function to return the sum of the elements located at the odd indices. 
And that's what I have right now:

```
def getSumOdds(aList):
    for element in aList:
        if element % 2 == 1:
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a study group, discussion forum or code writing service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links referenced in it.

Comment: When you post code or data please fomat it - https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: Who voted for this to be closed because it's too broad? That vote may be misplaced. There are a few ways to do it, true - however, the most Pythonic way uses the builtin `sum` function, as well as a generator in tandem with `enumerate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the code you've already started, [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) is probably the function you want which returns the count and the values in the list. Then we filter the odd indices and add them to a variable for the sum, as you had already done:

```
def getSumOdds(aList):
    total = 0
    for index, element in enumerate(aList): 
        if index % 2 == 1:
            total += element
    return total

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

print getSumOdds(l) # 20 (odd indices: 2+4+6+8=20)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are doing `for element in aList`, `element % 2 == 1` will check if *each element* is odd, not if its index is odd.

What you can do is this:

```
value = 0
for index in range(len(aList)):
    if index % 2 == 1:
        value += aList[value]
```

This goes through all of the *indices*, and if it's odd, adds the element *at that index* to the accumulator.

That method is fairly easy to understand; however, it goes through an unnecessary number of elements:

```
value = 0
for index in range(1, len(aList), 2):
    value += aList[index]
```

`range(x, y, z)` generates all elements counting up from `x` up to but not including `y`, counting by `z`. This starts at 1 and takes every 2 elements.

This is rather long though, and can be shortened to the following:

```
value = sum(aList[index] for index in range(1, len(aList), 2))
```

Using list slicing, where `aList[start:end:jump]` gives every `jump`-th element starting from `start` up to `end` (implicity the very end), you can do the following:

```
value = sum(aList[1::2])
```

This sums every second element starting from the first.

If your input is not necessarily indexable (that is, it's iterable but cannot use `[index]` syntax, such as a set, range, map, etc), you can do:

```
value = sum(val for index, val in enumerate(anIter) if index % 2 == 1)
```

This sums every value where the index is odd by getting the index and value for each enumerated value. The `enumerate` function is an iterable which returns `(0, a[0]), (1, a[1]), ..., (len(a) - 1, a[-1])`.

Comment: Note: You could handle arbitrary iterable (possibly non-indexable) types [with `itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) and avoid index calculations. `sum(itertools.islice(anIter, 1, None, 2))` and you don't need to track indices at all (and dropping unused values is handled efficiently at the C layer to boot). So really, the only two solutions worth considering speed and succinctness-wise are actual slice and `islice` approaches; the former is faster but sequence only, the latter is slower but handles all iterables.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Cool, thanks for the additional information!

Answer (score 0):

Just you can use a list slice `list[1::2]`
or function

```py
def getSumOdds(aList):
    return sum(aList[1::2])
```